# How to run .testssl.sh command on Linux platform and save the output in Json file and save the Json data in database

Tags: java, json, testssl.sh

I cloned git repository of testssl.sh on my desktop
Using the clone, i want to run below command on Linux platform and save the output to a .json file and read the file and save json data to a database.

```
./testssl.sh -p -s -f -U -S -P --jsonfile-pretty=mxtest.json https://www.google.com
```

Below is the piece of code i have tried so far

```
public void test1() throws IOException {
    String sURL = "https://www.google.com";
    runScript("/testssl.sh -p -s -f -U -S -P --jsonfile-pretty=mxtxt.json "+ sURL);
}

public void runScript(String command) throws IOException {

    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
       Process proc = rt.exec(command);
}
```

Unable command is unable to execute but when i run it is passing.

Comment: Have you tried to use your command as `./testssl.sh`, did your sh file is with `chmod +x` ?

Comment: A shell script won't run. You must run the shell with your script as parameter. https://www.netjstech.com/2016/10/how-to-run-shell-script-from-java-program.html